# Multiple X-Axes in Plotly

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, plotly

I'm currently trying to plot two different sets of data to create a visualization for the data we are processing.

Essentially, one set of data will be a cross-section of a river (width, depth).

[image: Cross-Section Plot]

The other set of data consists of water levels and the times those levels were recorded. (depth, time)

[image: Water Level Data Plot]

I'm currently plotting each in individual graphs, but need to make the plot overlay the water level data onto the cross-section data. This would require multiple X-Axes since the range is not the same. Is this possible in plotly? I've seen a video online of someone using Plotly's data editor, but haven't found much in terms of using their API.

Also, I know that one set of data is in meters, the other is in feet -- these data are being used as an example, the final result will both be displayed in feet.

Answer (score 11):

@emackey answer does not produce multiple x-axes. This is a working syntax that shows two different dataset on a same graph with one y axis and two x-axes.

```
var trace1 = {
      x: [1, 2, 3], 
      y: [40, 50, 60], 
      name: 'yaxis data', 
      type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
      x: [12, 13, 14], 
      y: [4, 5, 6], 
      name: 'yaxis2 data', 
      xaxis: 'x2', 
      type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
      yaxis: {title: 'yaxis title'}, 
      xaxis2: {
            title: 'xaxis2 title', 
            titlefont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'}, 
            tickfont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'}, 
            overlaying: 'x', 
            side: 'top'
      }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

This will produce the following graph.This [link](https://plot.ly/javascript/multiple-axes/) will help you for further documentation.

[image: This will produce the following graph]

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible using [subplots](https://plot.ly/javascript/subplots/).  Here's an example with a shared Y axis, and independent X axes.

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3], 
  y: [4, 3, 2], 
  xaxis: 'x2',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'trace1'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [200, 300, 400], 
  y: [2, 3, 4], 
  xaxis: 'x3',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'trace2'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  xaxis2: {
    domain: [0.0, 0.45]
  },
  xaxis3: {
    domain: [0.55, 1]
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```